How to dissolve inkjet printer ink
I have a very large (10x10 feet) B&W line drawing that was printed on plain paper with an inkjet plotter. I want to transfer this drawing onto a wooden surface to use it as a guideline for some work. It doesn't have to be razor-sharp and I don't care to destroy the original in the process, as long as it succeeds transferring the drawing faithfully.
As a kid I played with rubbing acetone on magazine pages to transfer the images on other surfaces. I thought of using the same technique for this drawing, but it proved harder than I thought. All the products I tried are failing to dissolve the ink.
I tried the following products that I had readily in my shop:

Ethyl alcohol 90%
Oil-based paint thinner
Lacquer thinner (containing methyl alcohol, toluene, acetone, ethyl acetate, xylene, ethyl ketone, ethyl benzene, ant petroleum distillate)
Pure acetone
Pure ethyl acetate

I tested by rubbing each product on the back side of a print sample with the printed side set against a wooden board.
Of all these products, only ethyl acetate showed some signs of rubbing off the black ink very lightly. I left a sample sheet clamped between an ethyl acetate-soaked rag and a wooden board for a minute or so, but nothing happened.
Does anybody know if there is another chemical that I can try on? the print comes from a printing studio and I don't  have the printer model, but maybe I can ask if that may help (and if they have the same printer still around—it was printed over a year ago).
Thanks for any help.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about chemistry.

You  might try overlaying a small test print on the board and spraying the back with plain water. It all depends on the ink used, and, for purposes of recycling paper, many modern ink-jet inks are water soluble -- but not all. As for plotters, check with the cartridge specs. That said, this is not a chemistry question.

I tried water too. I didn't include it in the list because it's part of the ethyl alcohol solution.

the fundamental question here is: what does inkjet ink dissolve in? Is that question not explicit? If it is, how is it not about chemistry?

Some inks are dye based (typically HP), some are pigment based (typically Epson). Pigment based one may by hard nuts to crack.

There are many types of ink used in inkjet printers (and also in vector-based plotters, which are different). You did not state the composition of the ink (solvents are often listed on cartridges or boxes for them), nor the brand and model of ink cartridge, so any answer is not based on chemistry, but on guesswork.

I contacted the print shop for information about their ink, if they come up with some useful information I will update my question.
